# Collection view Flow layout have perform paging concept?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I had integrate collection view flow layout horizontal And Vertical both but now i want perform paging concept on it.I want to know can i do this dynamically?

Comment: use **CCBottomRefreshControl** to add paging concept. And what do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: Please add what you have done in your code so some can help you.

Comment: @MRizwan33 I have used custom flow layout customize class ,I cant perform paging on it?

Comment: okay. In above commit pod will do your work please use it. if you don't understand it i will post answer with code before that let me know what you done.

Comment: https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

Comment: @Rizwan I used above library ,Now can u say In this can i perform Paging vertically?

Comment: it will perform vertically sure. but test horizontally yourself. i think it will work for both.

Comment: because it effects on scroll. it doesn't matter whether it vertical or horizontal.

Comment: @Rizwan I have tried but i have got error like "
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x604000a27d00> {length = 2, path = 13 - 1}'"

Comment: than post your code too. let us see how you are using it.

Comment: @Rizwan I cant post my code but please you have any demo for Paging in custom flowlayout as above github library?

Comment: i have posted if you still have any issue than let me know. my code is in objective c language.

Comment: Okay I will try this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Install pod file in your project.

> pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'

2. Import this file in your VC where you want to use paging.

> CCBottomRefreshControl/UIScrollView+BottomRefreshControl.h

3. Use the code below to add paging.

   ```
   -(void)bottomRefreshEnable{

       UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
       refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
       refreshControl.triggerVerticalOffset = 70;
       [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

       self.customScrollView.bottomRefreshControl = refreshControl;

   }
   ```
4. Last Method that will call when it detect scroll offset (that we kept 70 in above code).

   ```
   - (void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {


   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Check `isPagingEnabled = true` for your collection view.

Code style note: make sure to properly camelcase your variables.